# Can I redirect a spell that targets an "opponent" back to the caster?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Scenario 1:

My opponent casts [Appetite for Brains](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAppetite%20for%20Brains%5d), and in response I cast [Redirect](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRedirect%5d). Can I target him and redirect spell back at him?

Scenario 2:

I have a creature enchanted with [Snake Umbra](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSnake%20Umbra%5d). My opponent gains control over my creature through some effect. My opponent attacks me with that creature and deals damage with it. Does he get to draw a card?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In scenario 1, your opponent is still controlling Appetite for Brains, and since they aren't their own opponent, they are not a valid target for the spell. So you can't Redirect that spell back to them.

> 102.2. In a two-player game, a player's opponent is the other player.

---

In scenario 2, Snake Umbra bestows an ability on the *creature*, which is now controlled by the opponent. You are the opponent's opponent, so they do get to draw a card.

Note that if Snake Umbra would've read "Whenever **enchanted** creature deals damage to an opponent, you may draw a card.", nobody would draw a card; you control the trigger, but you're not your own opponent.

Only if Snake Umbra would've read "Whenever **enchanted** creature deals damage to **a player**, you may draw a card.", you would have drawn a card.

Comment: thank you for responding, I think this is correct answer